# How to ensure a piece of code is always used by one thread at any given time?

Tags: multithreading, rust, atomic

I'm writing a function that needs to use mutable static variables to work (a weird implementation of a message loop). In order to allow only one writer to access those variables at any given time, I need to make the access to this function exclusive (to the first thread that accesses it).

### Using [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html)

My first guess was to use an [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html):

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{Ordering, AtomicBool};

static FLAG: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);

fn my_exclusive_function() {
    if FLAG.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
        panic!("Haha, too late!")
    }
    
    FLAG.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);

    /* Do stuff */
}
```

This code has an obvious flaw: if two threads happen to read `FLAG` at the same time, they would both think that this is ok for them to continue.

### Using [`Mutex<()>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html)

Then I thought about using a [`Mutex<()>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) for its lock.

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

static FLAG: Mutex<()> = Mutex::new(());

fn my_exclusive_function() {
    let _lock = FLAG.try_lock() {
        Ok(lock) => lock,
        Err(_) => panic!("Haha, too late!"),
    };

    /* Do stuff */

    // `_lock` gets dropped here, another thread can now access the function
}
```

There are two problems here:

1. [`Mutex::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.new) is not a [`const` function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/functions.html#const-functions) which makes me unable to initialize the [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html). I could use a library like [`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) here but if I can avoid an additional dependency, it would be great.
2. Even if I use [`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static), a user-defined function (the handler inside of the message loop actually) could panic and poison the mutex. Here again, I could use a thread-party library like [`parking_lot`](https://crates.io/crates/parking_lot) but that would be yet anther additional dependency.

I'm willing to use those if there is no alternatives but if I can avoid it, that is better.

What would the right way to do this look like? Is it just a matter of [`Ordering`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html)?

#### Related question that did not help me

- [**How to ensure a portion of code is run by just one thread at a time?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010213/how-to-ensure-a-portion-of-code-is-run-by-just-one-thread-at-a-time) Answers are specifically focused on C# and .NET and involve features I don't have in Rust.

Comment: [`compare_exchange`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html#method.compare_exchange) / [`compare_and_swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html#method.compare_and_swap)

Comment: @Shepmaster Seems like magic to me x) What about the ordering? Is 
`Ordering::Relaxed` sufficient for this case? I'm fairly new to async programming.

Comment: (a) That's not async programming. (b) understanding the ordering has always eluded me. I use `SeqCst` so I don't have to think. The bookmark I have is [Atomic operations, std::atomic<> and ordering of writes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384901/155423)